# Pygame window flickering

Tags: python, pygame

This is my text adventure code, pieces. When i start my code, my buttons and windows always flickering, and i don't know how to fix that problem. I tried pygame.window.update(), but it did not bring anything. Maybe it's problem with FPS, i don't know. :)
...............................................................................

```
import pygame,sys


pygame.init()
#############
pygame.mixer.music.load('Invincible.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play()

#############

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)

red = (200,0,0)
green = (0,200,0)

bright_red = (255,0,0)
bright_green = (0,255,0)

block_color = (53,115,255)


gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('One Day After')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

gameIcon = pygame.image.load('gameicon.jpg')
pygame.display.set_icon(gameIcon)

pause = False

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()


def GameOver():
    ####################################
    pygame.mixer.Sound.play("smb_gameover.wav")
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    ####################################
    largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Game Over", largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)


    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()



        button("Play Again",150,450,100,50,green,bright_green,game_loop)
        button("Quit",550,450,100,50,red,bright_red,quitgame)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15) 

def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac,(x,y,w,h))
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            pygame.mixer.music.stop()
            action()

    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ic,(x,y,w,h))
    smallText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)


def quitgame():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()
    quit()

def unpause():
    global pause
    pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
    pause = False


def paused():
    ############
    pygame.mixer.music.pause()
    #############
    largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Paused", largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)


    while pause:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()


        button("Continue",150,450,100,50,green,bright_green,unpause)
        button("Quit",550,450,100,50,red,bright_red,quitgame)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)   


def game_intro():

    intro = True

    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        pilt1 = pygame.image.load('apoc2.jpg').convert()
        gameDisplay.blit(pilt1, [0,0])
        pygame.display.flip()


        button("Start",150,450,100,50,green,bright_green,game_loop)
        button("Quit",550,450,100,50,red,bright_red,quitgame)

        pygame.display.update()

def game_loop():
    global pause

    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
                quit()
        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        pygame.display.flip()
        Backgroundpic = pygame.image.load('back.jpg').convert()
        gameDisplay.blit(Backgroundpic, [0,0])
        pygame.display.flip()
        tekst = "This game will go as far as you choose!"
        meie_font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 36)
        teksti_pilt = meie_font.render(tekst, False, (50,50,155))
        gameDisplay.blit(teksti_pilt, (100, 250))
        tekst2 = "You are the smith of your destiny"
        meie_font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 36)
        teksti_pilt = meie_font.render(tekst2, False, (50,50,155))
        gameDisplay.blit(teksti_pilt, (100, 400))

        pygame.display.flip()









game_intro()
game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: `flip()` and `update()` makes almost the same - it sends image from buffer to video card which will display it - if you didn't draw all ellements before `flip()/update()` then you can see this as flickering. Use only one of them and only once in `while` loop -  at the end of the loop.

Comment: There can also other element which can makes flickering - if `flip/update()` sends data when video card is sending previous data on the screen then it can finally display half of previous data and half of new data - which may not fit one to another. On some system you can set `v-sync` to send data only when video card doesn't send data on screen - but PyGame doesn't use this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be flipping twice. You must flip only once, after everything is drawn. Remove the first call to `flip()` and your flicker should reduce.